# variable in WGAME woolf.sol confuses me

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, addresses, local-variables

Okay, so I was looking over the wolf contract(https://etherscan.io/address/0xeb834ae72b30866af20a6ce5440fa598bfad3a42#code), to understand how they fixed it and what happened... and one thing just doesn't make sense... I was hoping someone could clairfy it for me. On lines 37-42 of Woolf.sol  the following variables are labled

```
  **// reference to the Barn for choosing random Wolf thieves
  IBarn public barn;
  // reference to $WOOL for burning on mint
  WOOL public wool;
  // reference to Traits
  ITraits public traits;**
```

my question is, is this declared in the deployer, like an .env file in hardhat and does it refrence a contract address or address AND if it does how would you do that? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Two of those variables are initialized in the constructor.

```
  constructor(address _wool, address _traits, uint256 _maxTokens) ERC721("Wolf Game", 'WGAME') { 
    wool = WOOL(_wool);
    traits = ITraits(_traits);
```

And `barn` is initialized by calling `setBarn` function.

```
  function setBarn(address _barn) external onlyOwner {
    barn = IBarn(_barn);
  }
```

It is likely those contracts are deployed in a separate transaction. It is common to have a script that deploy several contracts passing around the addresses when they are required.